# API Gateway GET fails with "Missing Authentication Token" (but POST works)

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have a working Lambda + API Gateway "hello world" combination, as follows -

#### lambda.py

```
import boto3, json, logging

logger=logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)    

logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel(logging.WARNING)

def api_gateway(fn):
    def wrapped(event, context):
        body=json.loads(event["body"])        
        resp=fn(body, context)
        return {"statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
                "body": json.dumps(resp)}
    return wrapped

@api_gateway
def handler(event, context):
    logging.info("event: %s" % event)
    return {"hello": "world"}
```

#### api_gateway.yaml

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  FunctionName:
    Type: String
  StageName:
    Type: String
  FunctionArn:
    Type: String
  HttpMethod:
    Type: String
    Default: POST
Outputs:
  GatewayURL:
    Value: !Sub "https://${ApiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${StageName}"
Resources:
  ApiGateway:
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${FunctionName}-${StageName}"
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  ApiGatewayMethod:
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: !Ref HttpMethod
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub
          - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations"
          - lambdaArn: !Ref FunctionArn
      ResourceId: !GetAtt ApiGateway.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  ApiGatewayDeployment:
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      StageName: !Ref StageName
    DependsOn:
      - ApiGatewayMethod
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
  ApiGatewayPermission:
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !Ref FunctionArn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${ApiGateway}/*/${HttpMethod}/"
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
```

This works fine for a `POST` request -

```
curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://XXXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev -d "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
{"hello": "world"}
```

but I need a `GET` :/

I was hoping this would be a simple change, just change the gateway `HttpMethod` parameter to `GET` - which deploys fine, but when I try to ping it -

```
curl -X GET https://XXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

There are no errors shown in the Lambda logs so this looks like some kind of failure at the API Gateway level :(

Any ideas at to what to tweak in the API Gateway config to make a GET request work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to define an *extra* API Gateway resource to make this work -

```
Resources:
  ApiGatewayStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      DeploymentId: !Ref ApiGatewayDeployment
      StageName: !Ref StageName
```

With this, you should be able to make both `GET` and `POST` requests to work.

Without this, it seems that API Gateway will create some kind of "default" stage, one which will only support POST requests.